# Time in nanoseconds in lua script for Redis

Tags: redis, lua

I am running a lua script in redis something like below:

> eval "return tostring(tonumber(ARGV[1]))" 0 1538409827183989630

which should return `1538409827183989630` but is returning this `1.538409827184e+18` which is dropping last few nano second digits(Its a timestamp in nano seconds)

What is the correct way to do this assuming i need nano seconds precision cause i am comparing timestamps..

Comment: what type is `ARGV[1]`? is it really necessary to convert it to a number befor you convert it to a string?  if you want a specific format you should explicitly format your string using `string.format`

Comment: Yes, i need to convert it integer do comparison(not shown in the above example as it is irrelevant) and then return back as string

Answer (score 0):

Lua numbers have two subtypes, integer and float which Lua chooses automatically.

One of the few if not the only situation where you have to care about that difference is when you want to convert a number to a string.

`print(1538409827183989630)` will print `1538409827183989630`

`print(1538409827183989630.0)` will print as `1.538409827184e+18`

If you want to make sure you get the same output you'll have to explicitly format the string.

```
local int = 1538409827183989630
local float = 1538409827183989630.0

print(string.format("%d", int))
print(string.format("%d", float))
```

output:

```
1538409827183989630
1538409827183989504
```

You'll notice that there will be a difference between both numbers due to the float -> integer conversion.

Comment: I feel tonumber() always returns a float so i am always stuck with 1538409827183989504 what is other option to cast it to integer?

Comment: tonumber will return an integer if the string represents an integer. to convert a float to an integer you could use `math.floor()`

Comment: Then i am confused this code   eval "return string.format(\"%d\",tonumber(ARGV[1]))" 0 1538409827183989630  still prints 1538409827183989504

Comment: you cannot store all digits of that integer in a float. please read something about data types and the differences between integer and float

Comment: dude i know the difference, i guess you are failling to understand tonumber is giving me a float even when i am passing a whole number 1538409827183989630 or simply show me the code to print this 1538409827183989630 whole number from string converted to number using tonumber

Comment: looks like you're using a Lua version older than 5.3  there is no integer support below 5.3 so Lua cannot handle a number like 1538409827183989630 if you don't build your own interpreter